# How to scrape a word press based page? Respectively how to login to a page requesting username and Password

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, web-scraping, python-requests

So im quite unsure how to explain my issue. So - I try to **scrape** a schedule page (of my school) to make It easier to read. Unfortunately i couldnt figure how to pass the creditals to the login prompt with python.

url = "https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/ 
or rather this one due to it contains the actual data. 
url = https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/f1/subst_001.htm


I do know the password and username.

Login prompt looks like this :
[image]

As you might have guessed - i want to pass password and username to this prompt.
This code doesnt work for me - it returns unauthorized error.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
r = session.post("https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/",data={"log":"xxx","pwd":"xxx"})
#or
r = session.post("https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/f1/subst_001.htm",data={"log":"xxx","pwd":"xxx"})
print(r.content)
```

**output**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.diltheyschule.de Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

prolly essential information :

1. the goal is to scrape 'https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/f1/subst_001.htm'
2. passing pwd and log to the prompt (most likely without gui support (e.g. selenium))

Comment: You need to use Basic Auth: https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directory is secured by basic auth authentication. This is the easiest method of authentication where you can log in with the appropriate headers.

Are you also sure that you want to use POST method for see what is in .html page?

Please, try this:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()

r = session.get("https://www.diltheyschule.de/vertretungsplan/f1/subst_001.htm",auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
print(r.content)
```